# Using std::find with incremented iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

Lets say I have following code

```
std::vector<char> myvector = {'u', 'd', 'l', 'r', 'u'};
std::vector<char>::iterator it;

std::cout << "vector size = " << myvector.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "myvector.begin() = " << *(myvector.begin()+1) << std::endl;
it = find (myvector.begin() + 1, myvector.end(), *myvector.begin());
if (it != myvector.end())
{
  myvector.erase(myvector.begin());
  myvector.erase(it);
  std::cout << "Found and deleted " << '\n';
  std::cout << "vector size = " << myvector.size() << std::endl;
}
else
  std::cout << "Element not found in myvector\n";
```

By using `myvector.begin() + 1` in this line I do get a segmentation fault, and I have no idea why.

```
it = find (myvector.begin() + 1, myvector.end(), *myvector.begin());
```

Normally I should be able to increment the iterator by arithmetic. I even tried other solutions like `std::advance` or `std::next` but with no success.

Any suggestions?

@And yeah, what I want to achieve is check if the element has it duplicate and remove them both

Comment: Which line did the error occur on when you ran your program in the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line(s)

```
myvector.erase(myvector.begin());
myvector.erase(it);
```

are problematic. After you erase the first element, all other following iterators are invalidated, see [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase). Changing the order of the lines should make the code valid.

[<kbd>Live example on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3077882d184ece2)

Comment: Foolish me, proof that I should go to sleep(3 am here >.<)

Comment: @JohnnieW Ha ha, yeah, pointers or iterators don't mix well with lack of sleep. And btw, use `std::next` instead of raw iterator arithmetic.

Comment: any suggestion why should I do that? As far is know when working with such simple vectors raw arithmetic shouldn't harm me :)

Comment: @JohnnieW Indeed, for `std::vector`s it works just fine. However, `std::next` documents the intention better, it is as fast as adding 1, and can easily be searched for in a code review. Note that other types of iterators don't support random access, such as `forward_iterator`s, so `std::next` (or `++`) is necessary in that case. So it's better to keep your code as generic as possible and stick to `std::next` no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that your segmentation fault is on the line you think it is. I don't see anything wrong with that part.

I do see undefined behavior here:

```
myvector.erase(myvector.begin());
myvector.erase(it);
```

erase(), on a `std::vector`, invalidates all iterators past the erasure point. The first erase(), in this case, is going to invalidate `it`. In this case, with most common implementation of `std::vector`, including the one you're likely using, `it` will become the `end()` iterator, and that second `erase()` will become, essentially, "myvector.erase(myvector.end());".

Not kosher.

You should not rely on any behavior of vector iterators, in this case, and simply flip the order of erase() calls, here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I choosed that guy's answer as solution because he was the first one who answered, hope you understand :)